# Проблема установки пакетов npm через vpn-соединение

Tags: node.js, npm

При установке пакетов возникает такая проблема. Сижу через vpn соединение. Ни один пакет установить не получается.

```
$ npm i -g firebase-tools
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "-g" "firebase-tools"
npm ERR! node v6.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network socket hang up
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zebzeev_an\npm-debug.log
```

Манипуляции с config не помогают

```
$ npm config list
; cli configs
user-agent = "npm/3.10.7 node/v6.5.0 win32 ia32"

; globalconfig C:\Program Files\nodejs\etc\npmrc
https-proxy = "http://xxx:xxx@uk-repair.uralkali.com:8080/"
proxy = "http://xxx:xxx@uk-repair.uralkali.com:8080/"
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
strict-ssl = false

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\Users\zebzeev_an
; HOME = C:\Users\zebzeev_an
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'npm@latest' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.7
3 info using node@v6.5.0
4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\zebzeev_an/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
6 silly install loadCurrentTree
7 silly install readLocalPackageData
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData npm@latest
9 silly fetchNamedPackageData npm
10 silly mapToRegistry name npm
11 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
12 silly mapToRegistry registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
13 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
13 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'npm',
13 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
13 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'npm',
13 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'npm',
13 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
13 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
13 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
14 silly mapToRegistry uri http://registry.npmjs.org/npm
15 verbose request uri http://registry.npmjs.org/npm
16 verbose request no auth needed
17 info attempt registry request try #1 at 09:04:41
18 verbose request id 3a314638099759c6
19 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/npm
20 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: socket hang up
21 info attempt registry request try #2 at 09:04:52
22 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/npm
23 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: socket hang up
24 info attempt registry request try #3 at 09:05:53
25 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/npm
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: socket hang up
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:252:15)
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:344:23)
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for npm@latest { Error: socket hang up
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:252:15)
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:344:23)
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
27 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
28 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
29 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
30 silly install printInstalled
31 verbose stack Error: socket hang up
31 verbose stack     at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:252:15)
31 verbose stack     at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:344:23)
31 verbose stack     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
31 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
31 verbose stack     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
31 verbose stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
31 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
32 verbose cwd C:\Users\zebzeev_an
33 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
34 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "npm@latest"
35 error node v6.5.0
36 error npm  v3.10.7
37 error code ECONNRESET
38 error network socket hang up
39 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
39 error network and is related to network connectivity.
39 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
39 error network
39 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
39 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
40 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Может быть кто в курсе данной проблемы?

Comment: В логе есть url `http://registry.npmjs.org/npm`. В браузере он открывается? Настройки прокси браузера и npm совпадают?

Comment: укажите `http-proxy`.